# Правильный вывод значения из mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица, есть запрос на вывод

```
$sqlpre = mysql_query("SELECT `like` FROM `base` WHERE `id` = 31");
    $sqlpreone = $sqlpre + 1;
```

Но вместо того, чтобы присвоить переменной `$sqlpre` значение столбца `like` из записи с `id` = 31, он присваивает непонятную вещь (кажется 5).

Как починить это? Мне надо сделать так, чтобы переменной `$sqlpre` присваивалось значение, стоящее в столбце `like` записи с `id` = 31, а после всего этого переменной `$sqlpreone` присваивалось значение переменной `$sqlpre` + 1

Comment: Чтобы "починить", надо хотя бы почитать [документацию](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php) и посмотреть там примеры

Comment: @BOPOH после прочтения действительно пришёл к msql_result(), спасибо )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как ни удивительно, но для этого надо прочитать в документации, как пользоваться функцией mysql_query и посмотреть примеры её использования.

В процессе надо также обратить внимание на большую красную надпись о том, что данная функция устарела, и вместо неё надо использовать PDO

```
$like = $pdo->query("SELECT `like` FROM `base` WHERE `id` = 31")->fetchColumn();
$like = $like + 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$sqlpre = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `like` FROM `base` WHERE `id` = 31"),0);
$sqlpreone = $sqlpre + 1;
```

Должен сказать, что `mysql_query()` и `mysql_result()` давно устарели.

Comment: Спасибо большое, но если они устарели, чем можно заменить?

Comment: PDO. Смотрите пост Ипатьева